# How to get status of emails sent via Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

[image]

I want to ask some question related to AWS SES. Please help me with my queries.

1. As described in the above image that we need to pay $0 for the first 62000 emails if sending email 
   from ec2 hosted application. How does AWS SES know that i will send email from my ec2 instance hosted 
   application or from somewhere else or we need to code?
2. How can i get the list of emails that successfully send, which emails get bounces, complaints, 
   rejected? Mean i want a log of my sending emails. I do not want to login in AWS and watch dashboard multiple time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can detect sends from Amazon EC2 based on IP address range.

For detailed logs of email sends, see: [Monitoring Your Amazon SES Sending Activity - Amazon Simple Email Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-sending-activity.html)

There are options for Event messages and Notifications.

Comment: As AWS mentioned in their documentation that they will send a response mail of email sent by AWS SES. But when I try to send mail by AWS SES console I didn't get any response about  mail that I send.